# Files dissapearing with ffmpeg recursive conversion

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I started in askubuntu, asking for a way to convert recursively more than 14K of wma to mp3 extracting the wma files path from a txt file.
There was an answer that could cover my needs, but a bug appears. The first run with some hundreds worked ok. The second, some wma albums got converted, others entirely deleted. There were some modifications. And last time completely, deleted all wma without converting.

this was the original script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t files < wma-files.txt

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    out=`echo $file | sed "s:wma:mp3:"`
    probe=`avprobe -show_streams "$file" 2>/dev/null`
    rate=`echo "$probe" | grep "bit_rate" | sed "s:.*=\(.*\)[0-9][0-9][0-9][.].*:\1:"`
    avconv -i "$file" -ab "$rate"k "$out"
    rm "$file"
done
```

Then the adaptation with ffmpeg

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t files < wma-files.txt

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    out=`echo $file | sed "s:wma:mp3:"`
    probe=`avprobe -show_streams "$file" 2>/dev/null`
    rate=`echo "$probe" | grep "bit_rate" | sed "s:.*=\(.*\)[0-9][0-9][0-9][.].*:\1:"`
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -ab "$rate"k "$out" && rm "$file"
done
```

With the first one I converted many files. Other just get deleted. The ones deleted were always the same release (so, all tracks from a release). I can listen, and even convert them with Soundkonverter.

Both of them produces "no such file of directory" and when this happens, everything get deleted.

The partition where files are stored is a usb HDD ntfs, but also happens in my ext4 internal HD.
I'm under Xubuntu 14.04

Here the script running with avconv (which what I managed to convert some, but other get disappeared) http://pastebin.com/w5weqEws  and with ffmpeg (that didn't convert any) http://pastebin.com/3QkaPzvW

I can't find differences between successfully and deleted original wma's. But for example, while other progs like beets read and write the tags, puddletag and mp3tag (under wine) don't, until I converted them with soundkonverter.

As the person trying to help me there redirect me here on the original post https://askubuntu.com/questions/508278/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-convert-wma-to-mp3-recursively-importing-from-txt-file/508304#508304
I'm here asking for any help to make run an script like this. Or any to use ffmpeg to convert recursively the audio files. My capacity of understanding is short for being able to make something working just reading the docs.

So I ask a help to run this. If I miss any relevant information, just tell me.

NOTE: I want to add that doing the conversion with

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    out=`echo "$file" | sed s:wma:mp3:`
    avconv -i "$file" -ab 192k "$out"
    rm "$file"
done
```

It works in the same files (the ones that are deleted with the other). Only that it makes everything to 192k, so not good if I'm converting lower bitrate ones. And get this error "Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0" that seems something typical from avconv in 14.04. With ffmpeg I cant try because I don't find the way how to use it, even out of the script. I really don't understand the docs seems
.

NOTE2: This is a mediainfo exit from:

1- A typical wma that get disappeared always with the script

```
Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : WMA
Format version                           : Version 2
Codec ID                                 : 161
Codec ID/Info                            : Windows Media Audio
Description of the codec                 : Windows Media Audio 9 - 128 kbps, 44 kHz, stereo 1-pass CBR
Duration                                 : 2mn 25s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 2.21 MiB (99%)
Language                                 : English (US)
```

2- A Wma that got successfully converted (yes I'm using copies now, I can't risk specially some rare audios that I got on the road)

```
Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : WMA
Format version                           : Version 2
Codec ID                                 : 161
Codec ID/Info                            : Windows Media Audio
Description of the codec                 : Windows Media Audio 9 - 128 kbps, 44 kHz, stereo 1-pass CBR
Duration                                 : 4mn 35s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 4.21 MiB (99%)
Language                                 : English (US)
```

So, as I don't see difference, but maybe, I'm losing any data to look into?

Comment: For those attempting to debug, just a quick note I wanted to make (I'm the script writer he mentioned from askubuntu). The reason I set a specific constant bit rate was because of a bug in avconv that records incorrect bit rate info for variable bit rate files. This bug is supposedly fixed in ffmpeg so the line is probably extraneous now.

Comment: It would be helpful to show a few lines from `files` in the question itself and in general, not to rely on people visiting any external resources in order to answer your question. You have provided a lot of information but I think that some of it is irrelevant. As far as people here are concerned, you have a file, you extract some parameters from it and you pass them to another program. It sounds like the problem may lie with the files themselves, rather than your script.

Comment: Sorry for the irrelevant info, but as i dont know where is the problem, neither exactly how to present it. I dont understand your point, should I paste the report from pastebin here? I will not make less readable the question? And why if this wma, can be read with normal ubuntu players, tagged with different programs, and converted with unless soundkonverter (that is the only way I have for this) could have any problem? How I can identify them?

Comment: learn how to debug. You know that some files work ok. Run just 1 command for a working file, and examine the value of `$rate`. Now run on a failing file (presumably, you're working on copies (good for you!) ). and look at the value of `$rate` for this one, is there extra "stuff" in there? Feel free to edit your question with this info. At least is will remove a layer of questions for us readers. Looking at your code a little more closely, is the single trailing \` char really accurate? Use `$(cmd ...)` for modern cmd-substitution and remove another layer of ambiguity from your q. Good luck.

Comment: thanks @shellter first one trying to guide me. I posted the relevant mediainfo, but I don't see difference between one and the other. As I told before, Im not the author of the script (and Im not attached to it). Actually Im pretty illiterate about. And becouse of this, I cant get completely this what you say of replacing the character. How should I make the replacement? Actually as I dont know what is this single trailing for, I cant search for how to replace it. Sorry. Im motivated to learn, but there is a so huge amount of info out there, that is difficult to process without some help.

Comment: The <pre> tags were cutting out code between `<` and `>` so I changed it to indents for the code blocks. The script will probably make a lot more sense now.

Comment: @TheSchwa: Same massacre happened. The strange, since the beginning of this issue is that the "No such file or directory" is directed to the .mp3 file, that for sure, as the .wma got deleted in 0,001 second after running the script, was never created.